# React Native, How to keep focus(foreground) after opened a URL in browser

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I use `Linking.openURL` to opened a URL in browser.

```js
Linking.openURL('https://google.com');
```

Now, default browser be opened, my app loses the focus, it is running on background.

I hope my app can keep focus(foreground). Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview). You will render the webpage inside your application.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const MyWebComponent = () => {
  return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://google.com' }} style={{ flex: 1 }} />;
}
```

Comment: My demand is to open the URL with the default browser

Comment: When you open the browser your application must be in the background because only one application in iOS can be in the foreground.